# WooCommerce registration form, also safe fields for shipping details

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I allready searched the internet but could not find anything usefull or maybe I did not searched good enough. But I have the following issue/question.

We have a WooCommerce registration page, when somebody register the data is saved in "billing" fields.

I also want this data to be saved in the "Shipping" fields when somebody register with the form.
If they want to change this afterwards that should not be a problem but when they register the fields also should be saved under the "Shipping" information.

Is something like this possible and if yes, how? Maybe with a custom function?

I think you can use this hook:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'also_update_shipping_fields' );
```

But how can I populate the Shipping fields after registration?

EDIT:
I edit the code a bit, I did not test it yet but could it work like this?

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_billing_shipping_address_after_registraion' );  // Fires immediately after a new user is registered.
function add_billing_shipping_address_after_registraion( $user_id ) {
    $current_user = get_userdata( $user_id ); // Here we use get_userdata() and not wp_get_current_user().

    // Updating Shipping info
    if ( $current_user->billing_first_name != $current_user->shipping_first_name )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $current_user->billing_first_name );
    if ( $current_user->billing_last_name != $current_user->shipping_last_name )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $current_user->billing_last_name );
    if ( $current_user->billing_email != $current_user->shipping_email )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_email', $current_user->billing_email );
    if ( $current_user->billing_company != $current_user->shipping_company )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $current_user->billing_company );
    if ( $current_user->billing_address_1 != $current_user->shipping_address_1 )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $current_user->billing_address_1 );
    if ( $current_user->billing_address_2 != $current_user->shipping_address_2 )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $current_user->billing_address_2 );
    if ( $current_user->billing_city != $current_user->shipping_city )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $current_user->billing_city );
    if ( $current_user->billing_postcode != $current_user->shipping_postcode )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $current_user->billing_postcode );
    if ( $current_user->billing_country != $current_user->shipping_country )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $current_user->billing_country );
    if ( $current_user->billing_state != $current_user->shipping_state )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $current_user->billing_state );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hook you should use when the user is being created/registered is `user_register`.

So you would use this, where you hook to both `profile_update` and `user_register`:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'add_billing_shipping_address_after_registraion' ); // Fires immediately after an existing user is updated.
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_billing_shipping_address_after_registraion' );  // Fires immediately after a new user is registered.
function add_billing_shipping_address_after_registraion( $user_id ) {
    $current_user = get_userdata( $user_id ); // Here we use get_userdata() and not wp_get_current_user().

    // Updating Billing info
    if ( $current_user->user_firstname != $current_user->billing_first_name )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $current_user->user_firstname );
    if ( $current_user->user_lastname != $current_user->billing_last_name )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', $current_user->user_lastname );
    if ( $current_user->user_email != $current_user->billing_email )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $current_user->user_email );


    Here is all shipping meta key
    //'shipping_first_name',
    //'shipping_last_name',
    //'shipping_company',
    //'shipping_country',
    //'shipping_address_1',
    //'shipping_address_2',
    //'shipping_city',
    //'shipping_state',
    //'shipping_country',
    //'shipping_postcode'

    // Updating Shipping info
    if ( $current_user->user_firstname != $current_user->shipping_first_name )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $current_user->user_firstname );
    if ( $current_user->user_lastname != $current_user->shipping_last_name )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $current_user->user_lastname );
    if ( $current_user->user_email != $current_user->shipping_email )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_email', $current_user->user_email );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I only wants to fire it once with registration. So I can leave the action "profile_update" out right? Also, why do I need this part? // Updating Billing info? The billing fields are filled out when you register. I want to also fill out the shipping fields so I only need this // Updating Shipping info, right? And you are checking the "user_firstname" and "user_lastname", shouldnt you be checking the billing fields instead of the user fields? I will update my answer to make an example.